# Why is my Makefile rule not deleting .o files?

Tags: makefile, object-files

My `Makefile` works but I'm still getting the `main.o` file created when calling `make`.
I've been looking through Stack Overflow for topics like mine but I haven't been able to understand the reason.

Here's the `Makefile`'s content:

```
EXEC=program
SOURCES=main.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
CC=gcc -pthread -lpthread
CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -g

.PHONY: clean

default: $(EXEC)

main.o: main.c
clean:
    -rm *.o $(objects) program

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Case matters: `$(objects)` should be `$(OBJECTS)`

Comment: Your makefile only removes the `.o` files when you run `make clean`.  You don't run `make clean` by default.  It isn't clear whether you really want to remove the `.o` files after every build.  If you do, you will recompile the program every time you run `make`, which is not usually what people want.  If you're really sure, use `default: $(EXEC) clean` — but don't do that.  Actually, since the `clean` rule removes `program`, which is also `$(EXEC)`, writing that `default:` rule would, in fact, delete the program after it is compiled.  Not helpful

Comment: @Barmar — you're right (about case-sensitivity of macro names), but the `clean` rule will delete the `.o` files anyway because of the `*.o` part of the command line.  The command should probably also list `$(EXEC)` so that if the executable name is changed, the cleanup rule matches.

Comment: You normally want the `.o` intermediate files left around so you don't have to brute-force recompile everything on a tiny change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your object files removed after the build step just append the `rm -f *.o` command to the `$(EXEC)` target.

Also, a few notes pointed out in the comments:

- Makefile variable names are case-sensitive. Use either `objects` or `OBJECTS`, not both.
- Instead of hard-coding `program` in your `clean` target, you should instead use `$(EXEC)`. That way you won't have to change it every time you change your program's name.
- You usually want `.o` files to be left after compiling so you don't have to recompile everything after a small change.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Make delete your object files automatically -- and not rebuild them needlessly when the sources have not been changed -- by making them [intermediate files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) by means of the `.INTERMEDIATE` special target. Just add this line:

```
.INTERMEDIATE: $(OBJECTS)
```